Tkinter error: cannot use geometry manager pack inside . which already has slaves managed by grid
I have two programs and their layout is almost similar, but one works and one gives an error. What is the difference between them.
This is my first program which works fine:
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import messagebox

    class MainWindow(tk.Frame): 
        def init(self, parent): 
            super().init(parent) 
            self.parent = parent
        
        # Input fields
        self.label1 = tk.Label(self, text="Input 1")
        self.label1.grid(row=0, column=0)
    
        self.Input1 = tk.Entry(self)
        self.Input1.grid(row=0, column=1)
    
        self.label2 = tk.Label(self, text="Input 2")
        self.label2.grid(row=0, column=2)
    
        self.Input2 = tk.Entry(self)
        self.Input2.grid(row=0, column=3)
    
        # Buttons
        self.Addbtn = tk.Button(self, text="Add", command=self.add_numbers)
        self.Addbtn.grid(row=1, column=0, columnspan=2)
    
    
        self.Clrbtn = tk.Button(self, text="Clear", command=self.clear_inputs)
        self.Clrbtn.grid(row=1, column=2, columnspan=2)
    
        # Output field
        self.label = tk.Label(self, text="Output")
        self.label.grid(row=2, column=0)
    
        self.Output = tk.Entry(self)
        self.Output.grid(row=2, column=1, columnspan=3)
    
    def add_numbers(self):
        try:
            num1 = int(self.Input1.get())
            num2 = int(self.Input2.get())
            result = num1 + num2
            self.Output.delete(0, tk.END)
            self.Output.insert(0, str(result))
            self.result_window.update_result(result)
        except ValueError:
            messagebox.showwarning("Error", "Please enter valid numbers.")
    
    def clear_inputs(self):
        self.Input1.delete(0, tk.END)
        self.Input2.delete(0, tk.END)
        self.Output.delete(0, tk.END)
        self.result_window.update_result(0)
    
    def get_inputs(self):
        return [self.label1.cget("text"), self.label2.cget("text")]
    
    def get_outputs(self):
        return [self.label.cget("text")]
    
    
    if name == "main": 
        root = tk.Tk() root.title("Addition")
        main_window = MainWindow(root)
        main_window.pack(side=tk.TOP, padx=10, pady=10)
        root.mainloop()

This is my second program which gives the error:
import tkinter as tk 
from tkinter import filedialog 
from tkinter import ttk 
import numpy as np 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
import os 
import matplotlib.colors as mcolors

class MainWindow(tk.Frame): 
    def init(self, parent): 
    super().init(parent) 
    self.parent = parent 
    self.file_directory = "" 
    self.file_prefix = "" 
    self.total_frames = 0 
    self.frame_index = 0 
    self.playing = False 
    self.width=0 
    self.height=0 
    self.setup_ui()

    def setup_ui(self):
        self.label1 = tk.Label(self.parent, text="Thermal File:")
        self.label1.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=5, pady=5)
    
        self.entry1 = tk.Entry(self.parent, width=30)
        self.entry1.grid(row=0, column=1, padx=5, pady=5)
    
        self.button1 = tk.Button(self.parent, text="Open", command=self.open_file)
        self.button1.grid(row=0, column=2, padx=5, pady=5)
    
        self.label2 = tk.Label(self.parent, text="Total Frames:")
        self.label2.grid(row=1, column=0, padx=5, pady=5)

        self.entry2 = tk.Entry(self.parent, state="readonly")
        self.entry2.grid(row=1, column=1, padx=5, pady=5)
    
        self.label3 = tk.Label(self.parent, text="Frame Number:")
        self.label3.grid(row=2, column=0, padx=5, pady=5)
    
        self.entry3 = tk.Entry(self.parent, state="readonly")
        self.entry3.grid(row=2, column=1, padx=5, pady=5)
    
        self.prev_button = tk.Button(self.parent, text="Previous", command=self.prev_frame)
        self.prev_button.grid(row=3, column=0, padx=5, pady=5)
    
        self.play_button = tk.Button(self.parent, text="Play/Pause", command=self.play_pause)
        self.play_button.grid(row=3, column=1, padx=5, pady=5)
    
        self.next_button = tk.Button(self.parent, text="Next", command=self.next_frame)
        self.next_button.grid(row=3, column=2, padx=5, pady=5)
    
        self.stop_button = tk.Button(self.parent, text="Stop", command=self.stop)
        self.stop_button.grid(row=4, column=0, padx=5, pady=5)

        self.horizontal_slider = tk.Scale(self.parent, from_=0, to=100, orient="horizontal", command=self.slider_callback, length=300)
        self.horizontal_slider.grid(row=4, column=1, padx=5, pady=5)


    def open_file(self):
        filename = filedialog.askopenfilename(title="Select Thermal File", filetypes=(("Text files", "*.txt"),))
        if filename:
            self.file_directory = os.path.dirname(filename)
            self.file_prefix = os.path.splitext(os.path.basename(filename))[0][:-1]
            self.total_frames = self.get_total_frames()
            self.entry2.config(state="normal")
            self.entry2.delete(0, tk.END)
            self.entry2.insert(0, str(self.total_frames))
            self.entry2.config(state="readonly")
            self.horizontal_slider.set(0)
            self.frame_index = 0
            data=[]
            with open(filename, 'r') as file:
                content=file.readlines()
            
            self.height=int(content[0])
            self.width=int(content[1])
    
            for line in content[2:]:
                data.extend([float(val) for val in line.split()])
    
            # Convert array to numpy array
            data = np.array(data)
    
            # Reshape the data as per the frame size (assuming 640x512 here)
            data = data.reshape(self.width, self.height)
    
            return data



    def get_total_frames(self):
        frame_number = 0
        while True:
            filename = os.path.join(self.file_directory, f"{self.file_prefix}{frame_number}.txt")
            if not os.path.exists(filename):
                break
            frame_number += 1
        return frame_number
    
    
    def play_pause(self):
        if self.playing:
            self.playing = False
        else:
            self.playing = True
            self.play_frames()

    def play_frames(self):
        delay=300
        while self.playing and self.frame_index < self.total_frames:
            #self.display_frame()
            self.frame_index += 1
            self.entry3.config(state="normal")
            self.entry3.delete(0, tk.END)
            self.entry3.insert(0, str(self.frame_index))
            self.entry3.config(state="readonly")
            self.horizontal_slider.set((self.frame_index / self.total_frames) * 100)
    
            self.parent.update()
            self.parent.after(delay)
    
    def stop(self):
        self.playing = False
        self.frame_index = 0
        self.entry3.config(state="normal")
        self.entry3.delete(0, tk.END)
        self.entry3.insert(0, "0")
        self.entry3.config(state="readonly")
        self.horizontal_slider.set(0)


    def prev_frame(self):
        if self.frame_index > 0:
            self.frame_index -= 1
            self.update_frame_entry()
    
    def update_frame_entry(self):
        self.entry3.config(state="normal")
        self.entry3.delete(0, tk.END)
        self.entry3.insert(0, str(self.frame_index))
        self.entry3.config(state="readonly")
    
    
    def next_frame(self):
        if self.frame_index < self.total_frames - 1:
            self.frame_index += 1
    
    def slider_callback(self, value):
        self.frame_index = int((int(value) / 100) * self.total_frames)
    
  
    def get_inputs(self):
        return []
    
    def get_outputs(self):
        return []
    
    def get_data(self):
        return self.open_file()

if name == "main": 
    root = tk.Tk() 
    root.title("Thermal File")
    main_window = MainWindow(root)
    main_window.pack(side=tk.TOP, padx=10, pady=10)
    root.mainloop()

I tried to debug but still I don't understand what difference makes them work.

Why do you use self.parent instead of self as the parent of the widgets created inside MainWindow in second program?

Also it should be __init__(...) instead of init(...).

I agree with acw1668 that passing parent rather than self as the parameter to the various UI elements is the most obvious difference that would have a tangible effect. It's not clear what the error is in the description "one gives an error".


This is my first program which works fine:

The first program doesn't work. Because we re using Python 3 or later.
The problem can be fixed.
You're making three typo errors so far.
Without using underscore:
You getting a blank widgets.
Screenshot:

To fix this.
Change this:
def init(self, parent): 
    super().init(parent) 

to with underscore:
def __init__(self, parent): 
    super().__init__(parent)

Change this:
if name == "main": <-- missing underscore

To:
if __name__ == "__main__": <-- added underscore

Change this:
root = tk.Tk() root.title("Addition")

To split to two lines:
root = tk.Tk()
root.title("Addition")

Screenshot:


This is my second program which gives the error:

The problem can be fixed.
You're making three typo errors so far.
Change this:
def init(self, parent):  <--- missing underscore
    super().init(parent) <--- missing underscore 

To:
def __init__(self, parent):  <--- added underscore
    super().__init__(parent) <--- added underscore

Change this:
if name == "main": <-- missing underscore

To:
if __name__ == "__main__": <-- added underscore

....
_tkinter.TclError: cannot use geometry manager pack inside . which already has slaves managed by grid

Change pack() to grid():
main_window.pack(side=tk.TOP, padx=10, pady=10)

This is my first program which works fine:
To:
main_window.grid(sticky='n', padx=10, pady=10) <--- used `sticky`

Screenshot:

